# How to create the equivalent of Rust's enum variant classes, or kotlin sealed classes in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a variant type in typescript, for HTTP responses, which can have several states. In rust, I could create this type as:

```rust
enum Response<T> {
    Empty,
    Loading,
    Failure(String),
    Success(data: T),
}
```

The same could be done in kotlin using sealed classes:

```kotlin
sealed class Response<out: T> {
  object Empty: Response<Nothing>()
  object Loading: Response<Nothing>()
  class Failure(val err: string): Response<Nothing>()
  class Success(val data: T): Response<T>
}
```

Is there any way to create this variant type in typescript?

Comment: Looks like a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @gabriele-petrioli for the idea of using a discriminated union.

```
type EmptyState = {
  kind: "empty";
};

type LoadingState = {
  kind: "loading"
};

type FailedState = {
  kind: "failed"
  msg: string;
};

type SuccessState<T> = {
  kind: "success"
  data: T;
};

type RequestState<T> =
  | EmptyState
  | LoadingState
  | FailedState
  | SuccessState<T>;

function parse<T>(res: RequestState<T>) {
  switch (res.kind) {
    case "failed":
      res.msg;
      break;
    case "success":
      res.data;
  }
}
```